# Html.BeginForm does not carry its current params

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "home", new { param1 = "value1" }, FormMethod.Get ))
{
     @Html.TextBox("Search", ViewBag.Search as string)
     <button type="submit">Search </button>
}
```

The HTML Output looks like this:

```
 <form action="/home/search?param1=value1" method="get">  
     <input id="Search" name="Search" type="text" value="">
     <button type="submit">Search </button>
 </form>
```

and My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Search(string param1, string search)  
{
    // param1 returns as "null" 
    // search contains the value that was inside the textbox
}
```

Anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can create a `hidden-field` for `param1`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of recommendations

- Use your form with a POST
- I would always recommend using a strongly typed view model, it has a number of benefits

So your code becomes:

```
public class SearchViewModel {
    public string param1 {get;set;}
    public string search {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost] // <-- were you missing this before?
public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)  
{
   // access with model.param1
}

@model SearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "home", FormMethod.POST ))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.param1)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.search)
     <button type="submit">Search </button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selman22 suggested the right way to accomplish this. Instead of placing the params on the actual URL, you put them in a hidden form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("search", "home", null, FormMethod.Get ))
{
     <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="@ViewBag.Param1Value.ToString()" /> 
     @Html.TextBox("Search", ViewBag.Search as string)
     <button type="submit">Search </button>
}
```

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Also you can use [Html.Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569498(v=vs.111).aspx) helper method. :)